# Automatic editing files on ftp

Tags: python, json, csv, ftp, salesforce

So, here's the scenario: once a day, a csv file is delivered to my ftp server. I need to import this information in to my CRM system (Salesforce). For this operation I planned on using skyvia.com, and their scheduling service. The challenge is that the csv comes without header on the columns, and skyvia does not handle this.

So the questions:

1. Is it possible to automatically insert a header row in csv files on ftp server? I will most likely hire a freelancer to do this, but i need to know what I am asking for. Is a python web script/application able to handle this?
2. Is there any alternative to skyvia that will handle import csv without column headers?
3. Is there any other solution to handle this import operation, without editing csv, or using Skyvia, that could handle this for Salesforce?

I am techie enough to handle some operations on my own, but I do know my limits...

Answer (score 1):

FTP protocol does not allow you to insert a line to a beginning of a file.

You would have to download the whole file, edit it locally, and re-upload it back.

Like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP(host, user, passwd)

f = BytesIO()
# Write header
f.write(str.encode("header\n"))
path = "/remote/path/file.csv"
# Append original contents
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + path, f.write)
# Re-upload back
f.seek(0, 0)
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + path, f)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Newbie question though: this code is performed on terminal window/Mac?

Comment: You run the code using `python`. So yes, typically on the terminal. Whatever OS you have.

Comment: Ok, but I would need this to be an automated task, on a schedule, not dependent on  a computer running, like a web aplication or something like this. What are the ways to handle this?

Comment: So run the python using a scheduling tool of your OS. Every OS has such tool. E.g. *Task Scheduler* in Windows or `cron` in Linux (and Mac OS X). That's not a programming question though.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the file size you can use `pysftp` to get the CSV file, add a header row, and then simply put it back up.  The reason I say it depends on the size is because there are some unresolved bugs in the `paramiko` library that causes it to fail on large >1GB files.

From the documentation you would do something like:

```
import pysftp

remote_file = 'some_file_name.csv'

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="your_FTP_server", username="your_username",
    password="your_password")

# Download the file from the remote server
srv.get(remote_file)

# Add the header
with open(local_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    rows = [r for r in csvfile]
rows = ['domain'] + rows

with open(local_path, 'wb') as csvfile:
    for row in rows:
        csvfile.write(row + '\n')


# To upload the file, simple replace get with put. 
srv.put(local_path)

# Closes the connection
srv.close()
```

Comment: The question is about FTP, not SFTP – And it also a way simpler to do this with Paramiko and file-like objects anyway. `f = BytesIO(); f.write(str.encode("header\n")); sftp.getfo(remote_file, f); f.seek(0, 0); sftp.putfo(f, remote_file);`