# Is It possible to edit a file through FTP in Python?

Tags: python, ftp, discord

I am working on a Python bot where the code is being hosted by Heroku.
One of the features I've added allows users to register a gamertag and it associates it with their Discord username, saving to a CSV file. Pretty straightforward. However, things are quite confusing for me, as I do not have access to the updated files after things get run on Heroku. So, once this CSV gets updated, I cannot access it in any way, and once the code stops running, or there is a break, it reruns everything from the original files I uploaded, losing all the information stored in the CSV.

I now want to try storing these values on my website via FTP. I've looked around and can't find ways to do this.
I know how to access and possibly upload using Python, but I would like to edit them directly.

Is this possible?

Comment: FTP doesn't allow file editing per se.  You would have to copy the file to the local machine, edit it there, and copy it back — all the while hoping nothing else changes the file on the remote machine between the time you copy it and the time you copy it back.  They invented this thing called a 'database' — wonderful gadgets; they take care of consistency problems like that.

Comment: some IDEs can edit files on FTP but they simply download it, edit it locally and send it back. As I know FTP may not give access to any editor on server so you can't edit it directly on server. With SSH you could have access to editors on server  ie. `vim`, `emacs`, `nano` and commands useful in automate editing - ie `sed`, `grep`, `awk` - but also to Python installed on server so you could even run Python code to automatically change file on server.

Comment: maybe you should change code and it should at start check if csv exist and copy it to new name (ie. with current date in name) to keep it.

Comment: Then, is it possible, whenever a request is made, the CSV gets read and that data gets stored in a buffer, adds/updates data and then overwrites the file?
I need all of this to happen without saving the data to a local file.

Comment: what request? I don't understand what and when you try to do.

Comment: I have a code written so that when users type "$register " followed by their username, it links the username to their Discord name. This then gets written to the CSV. 
But, now I want to store this CSV on my website and access then store it from FTP (file on my website) into a buffer.

Comment: and if you try with sftp ??   https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments.
I believe it's working now.

Using the FTP library to access the file and the StringIO library to read it.

```
ftp = FTP('server')
ftp.login('username','password')
string = StringIO()
ftp.retrlines('RETR /filepath.json', string.write)
```

So, this way it gets read as a string and then using the JSON library, I parse it.

```
stored = json.loads(string.getvalue())
```

Then, appending the necessary lines of code using **json.append()**.

Converting the string into bytes.

```
dump = bytes.(json.dumps(stored), 'utf-8')
```

Finally, writing new data to overwrite original file.

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR /filepath.json', io.BytesIO(dump))
```

I might be over-complicating things, but somehow, it's finally working. And I can easily access the file where the data gets stored.
Life is great.

Comment: For a consistency, you should use either `retrlines` + `storlines` or `retrbinary` + `storbinary`, instead of combining them + Other than that, your approach is correct. For a similar question, see [Automatic editing files on ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57998607/850848).